# Need help with basic Twitter implementation in PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I once had a decent implementation of my Twitter feed on my website but apparently Twitter's authentication has changed and all my functionality is broken.  All I need to do is retrieve my timeline, including tweets and retweets - nothing fancy, not an app, nothing.

I'm having a terribly hard time finding any resources to help me do this.  I need things spelled out for me clearly and concisely, which none of the tutorials I've found (especially on Twitter) seem to do.  Can anybody help me?  Please?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Twitter now uses oAuth for their API authentication.  You can find a large number of PHP oAuth frameworks/libraries out there that should be able to facilitate your needs.  I have used twitteroauth by Abraham Williams.  You can find it easily enough on GitHub.